# argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type FLUTTER GETX

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm a new flutter user by trying the getx method, this time I have a problem when I want to call the view, the error says `

> The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'ApiRepository'.

To solve this problem, do you think anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Here is the code snippet

**main_tab.dart** (*This Error*)

[image]

**home_controller.dart**

[image]

Comment: Please read [why not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and instead of image you could copy the code and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says clearly.

**Your param `apiRespostiry` can't access a null value.**

So, you can do two things:

1. Don't pass a null value
2. use ?  => `final ApiRepository? apiRepository`

Answer (score 1):

Due to the feature `null safety` of *dart* language, you can have more information in [Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

You need to put `?` sign after the type, if your variable might be `null`